# Content-Length is not set by default in jersey api for formdata

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client, content-length

Using postman I am able to get response but the jersey API gives bad response as it is not setting the content length by default. below is my code part.

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("X-FeApi-Token", apiToken )
                                     .header( "X-FeClient-Token",clientToken)
                                     .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=----"+boundary+"----")                                                           
                                     .header("Host","")
                                     .header("Accept","application/json")                                                                        
                                     .post( ClientResponse.class,formData);
```

Postman tool has content-length header by default and they have mentioned like the value for the content length will be calculated while sending request. it gives success response.

**Success Response When Content-Length is checked in postman**

[image]

In jersey API, it is giving bad response even though there is content-length header added. jersey API gives bad response which is same as the response from postman when I uncheck the content length header.

**Error Response When Content-Length is not checked in the postman**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) is enabled or not? If it is enabled the `Content-Length` header will be omitted as the length of the respective segments is sent at the start of each chunk.

Comment: I have added  client.setChunkedEncodingSize(null); but still getting the same error response